# How to pass function as a parameter instead of a value in c++ Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++

So i want to use GetPlayerViewPoint() in Unreal Engine, i wrote this code which works:

```
void UGrabber::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)

    {
        Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

        FRotator rot = GetOwner()->GetTransform().GetRotation().Rotator();
        FVector loc = GetOwner()->GetTransform().GetLocation();

        GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()->GetPlayerViewPoint(loc, rot);
    }
```

but i dont understand why this doesnt work, when i pass into GetPlayerViewPoint() chain of functions that return the same value, as i previously stored in a variable:

```
void UGrabber::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
    Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

    GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()->GetPlayerViewPoint(GetOwner()->GetTransform().GetLocation(), GetOwner()->GetTransform().GetRotation().Rotator());
}
```

Comment: Does your loc come from location and rot from rotation? In this case, you pass these arguments in reverse order.

Comment: I meant you swapped them in the second call.

Comment: you re right, but still it doesnt work even with reversed order

Comment: _"doesnt work"_ is vague to the point of being useless. How does it not work? Did you get a compiler error? Did your computer implode? The universe end? What happened (or didn't happen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is becaouse these two arguments are passed by reference:

```
virtual void GetPlayerViewPoint
(
    FVector & Location,
    FRotator & Rotation
) const
```

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/APlayerController/GetPlayerViewPoint/index.html - official documentation

To find out how passing arguments by reference works, see this tutorial - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.cbclx01/cplr233.htm